# Balsamiq Mockups isn't working

Tags: bug, status-completed, mockups

Today other users and I have been unable to use Balsamiq Mockups in posts. When clicking the Balsamiq icon the modal window opens up but Balsamiq never loads. I tested in the latest release versions of Firefox and Chrome

Is this a common problem? It worked for me and plenty of users last week, best I can tell it suddenly stopped working very recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are building out as we speak to fix this issue.  It should be available in the next 10 mins.